# UILabel background image same width label size with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, image, background, uilabel

I have been searching on the internet for couple of days but could't find any solution.

Finally figure out how to do:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
   SampleImageCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.sampleImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[sampleImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   cell.sampleTitleLabel.text=[sampleTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
   CGSize imgSize = cell.sampleTitleLabel.frame.size;

   CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(319,9999);
   CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.sampleTitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.recipeTitleLabel.font
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                      lineBreakMode:cell.sampleTitleLabel.lineBreakMode];

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
   [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,expectedLabelSize.width,expectedLabelSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   cell.sampleTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
   return cell;
}
```

I have seen some updated version for IOS7 but haven't try yet.
Hope this code helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the way in which you take the size of the label, in iOS 7 the method `sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:` is deprecated, try to use this code:

```
...
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(319,9999);
CGRect labrect = [cell.sampleTitleLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                             attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.recipeTitleLabel.font} 
                                             context:Nil];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,labrect.size.width,labrect.size.height)];

...
```